# How to play Xbox 360 NTSC-J games in Europe?

Tags: xbox-360, region-lock

I was 6-months in Japan and played Monster Hunter Frontier Online(who looks to be ip adress restricted game) with my hostfamilly' japanese ip adress and everything was perfect.

Before coming back to Europe (France) i finally decided to buy a Xbox 360 NTSC-J console and MonsterHunter 's NTSC-J games hoping to play it again, i already have ms points/gold live -japan.

Everything i bought (console, games, dlc, microsoft points and gold live) are legit.
I contacted Microsoft Customer Service, and i was told that i am able to play it with a japanese ip adress only (they suggested me to use a vpn service), that they don't ban for having another ip adress and that everything look legit according that i didn't modify the console and i have good behaviour with players.

How to play it again with a japanese ip adress ?

I heard that HongKong players are able to play it, but i don't know myself how.
I read around the web that we can setup a vpn router(aslo told by microsoft) with a vpn japanese server.

Can you help me ?
Please.
Thank you.

Comment: To play a legit NTSC-J games i have : Xbox360 NTSC-J console + Xbox Live -japan account + MS points-japan. Recommanded VPN service who worked on the PC version are : MobileFree.jp VPN ; EVPN/Easy2game and maybe StrongVPN and HideMyAss VPN service.

Comment: My new Internet Service Provider will probably achieve me to have stable 50Mbs Download and 5Mbs Upload, with a vpn service installed on it and few speed improvment, i can hope to have more than 5Mbs Download.

Comment: This isn't really something gamers would have particular expertise in.  Perhaps you could try asking at Super User?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it is more of a technical side issue, furthermore it feels like you already have the answer. That you just need to set it up through your ISP. Most aftermarket technical support company's should be able to walk you through the process. You may need to have two routers running off of the same modem. One with your local ip and one with your Japanese ip, and then just switch back and forth.